# Frama-c installation- configure: error: Cannot find ocamlfind

Tags: macos, ocaml, frama-c, ocamlfind

```
xhy0908deMacBook-Pro:frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501 xhy0908$ ./configure
configure: ******************
configure: * CONFIGURE MAKE *
configure: ******************
checking for make... make
checking version of make... 3.81
configure: *****************************
configure: * CONFIGURE OCAML COMPILERS *
configure: *****************************
checking for ocamlc... ocamlc
checking version of OCaml... 4.05.0
checking OCaml library path... /usr/local/lib/ocaml
checking for ocamlopt... ocamlopt
checking ocamlopt version and standard library... ok
checking for ocamlfind... no
configure: error: Cannot find ocamlfind.
```

When I try to start Frama-C on mac and run ./configure command. It said that it cannot find ocamlfind. But I have already installed it.

```
xhy0908deMacBook-Pro:frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501 xhy0908$ opam install ocamlfind
[NOTE] Package ocamlfind is already installed (current version is 1.7.3).
```

I don't know what the problem is.....

Comment: Have you tried running `eval $(opam config env)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OPAM you need to activate it with

```
eval `opam config env`
```

or, an alternative syntax, as @glennsl suggested,

```
eval $(opam config env)
```

This command will set up the PATH variable, so that `ocamlfind` become visible.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!  But each time I want to run frama-c from terminal, I need to run this command again?

Comment: yep, until you add to your profile, you probably did this when you installed opam, just didn't relogin yet. If not, the run `opam init --auto-setup` and it will do that for you.